# Foreach in php alternative?

Tags: php, foreach

Hi i want to know if this can be done without a foreach loop. I am trying to extract data but it keeps looping. i just want to run it once and store the values an array. Please can you assist me in doing this. I am new to php so i apologize if it seems to basic. Thanks in advance.

```
foreach ($result->titles as $title)
{
  "Title ID" => $title->id,
  "Title" => $title->title_name,
  "Created On" => $month_created_on,
  "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
  "Status" => $title->status,
}
```

Comment: What are those keys? What array do they belong to?

Comment: and where does the data come from ? what do you wanna do (read data or write ?).

Comment: The keys are used to identify fields that i am writing to. I am reading and writing data. the data is reading fine. i want to write this data into another file but the problem is it outputs each time. I just want the lastest keys displayed when the page is refreshd. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To run once, you don't need a loop. Just directly access the first element in the `$result->titles` array. This assumes the array is numerically indexed and that the first element is at index `0`. If this is not the case, modify the `[0]` to reference the first element.

```
$title_data = array(
    "Title ID" => $result->titles[0]->id,
    "Title" => $result->titles[0]->title_name,
    "Created On" => $month_created_on,
    "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
    "Status" => $result->titles[0]->status,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
"Title ID" => $title->id
```

It is associative array notation where you are using *Title ID* as the key and `$title->id` as the value. In order to make the code you have work, it would need to be like this:

```
foreach ($result->titles as $title)
{
   $newValues[] = array("Title ID" => $title->id,
                      "Title" => $title->title_name,
                      "Created On" => $title->month_created_on,
                      "Solved On" => $title->solved_on ,
                      "Status" => $title->status
                      );
}
```

But all that really does is reassign the `$result->titles` array as an associative array with your own custom keys. I'm not sure if that is even what you want.

To get the first element of the `result->titles` do something like this:

```
$title_id = $result->titles[0]->id;
$title_name = $result->titles[0]->title_name;
// etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can you can use a combination of `while` and `each` to achieve the same thing `foreach` can do

Example

```
$all = array ();
while ( list ( , $data ) = each ( $result->titles ) ) {
    $array = array ();
    while ( list ( $key, $value ) = each ( $data ) ) {
        $array [$key] = $value;
    }
    $all [] = $array;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r ( $all );
```